# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\Xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php, laravel

I want to install laravel 5.2. but it gives me that error.

[image]

This is the Error Message

```
Warning: require(D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel_project\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

Comment: what command you are runnuing

Comment: Have you ran `composer install`

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel new_project 5.2

Comment: paste the message, not an image

Comment: try with this command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: This command Not working